# Menu button can only be clicked one time

Tags: android

I added a custom menu to the menu button using the following code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        if (getDisplayedView() instanceof WorkspaceView) {
            ((WorkspaceView) getDisplayedView()).showEditMenu();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and

```
public void showEditMenu() {
        new EditMenu(lexs, ((Project) projects.getSelectedItem()).getName(), ((ProjectList) projectsList.getSelectedItem()).getName()).show();
    }
```

The EditMenu is implemented the following way:

```
public class EditMenu {

    private final String DELETE_PROJECT = "Projekt löschen";
    private final String DELETE_LIST = "Liste löschen";
    private final String RENAME_PROJECT = "Projekt umbenennen";
    private final String RENAME_LIST = "Liste umbenennen";
    private final String CLOSE = "Menü schliessen";

    private Context context;
    private String projectName;
    private String listName;
    private AlertDialog alert;

    private final CharSequence[] items = {DELETE_PROJECT, DELETE_LIST, RENAME_PROJECT, RENAME_LIST, CLOSE};

    public EditMenu(Context context, String projectName, String listName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.listName = listName;
    }

    public void show() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(projectName + ": " + listName);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals(DELETE_PROJECT)) {
                    deleteProject();
                } else if (items[item].equals(DELETE_LIST)) {
                    deleteList();
                } else if (items[item].equals(RENAME_PROJECT)) {
                    renameProject();
                } else if (items[item].equals(RENAME_LIST)) {
                    renameList();
                } else if (items[item].equals(CLOSE)) {
                    close();
                }
            }
        });
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private void deleteProject() {

    }

    private void deleteList() {

    }

    private void renameProject() {

    }

    private void renameList() {

    }

    private void close() {

    }
}
```

This works correctly if I click the menu button the first time. But if the context menu is closed and i click the menu button a second time, nothing happens.

I also tried to call

alert.close(), alert.hide(), alert.dismiss(), etc in the method close(), but it doesn't improve the situation. any hints? thankS¨!

Comment: I found the answer by myself: I have to overwrite public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) instead of public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no other answer in almost 3 weeks, I'll answer my question by myself:

Instead of overwriting

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

one has to override

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

Here a short example how to do it:

In the activity there is the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        showMenu();
        return true;
}

private void showMenu() {
        EditMenu menu = new EditMenu(this, "Pacman Menu");
        menu.show();
}
```

Then the clsas EditMenu looks for example the following way:

```
public class EditMenu {

    private final String QUIT = "Quit";
    private final String RESTART = "New Game";
    private final String SOUND = "Switch Sound";
    private final String PAUSE = "Un/pause";
    private final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[] {QUIT, RESTART, SOUND, PAUSE};

    private Context context;
    private String title;
    private AlertDialog alert;
    private MenuListener listener = new MenuListener();

    public EditMenu(Context context, String title) {
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void show() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.splashscreen);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setItems(items, listener);
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private class MenuListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals(QUIT)) {
                ((PacmanGame) context).quitGame();
            } else if (items[item].equals(RESTART)) {
                ((PacmanGame) context).restart();
            } else if (items[item].equals(SOUND)) {
                Sound.setSoundOn(! Sound.isSoundOn());
            } else if (items[item].equals(PAUSE)) {
                ((PacmanGame) context).getGameBoard().setPausing(!(((PacmanGame) context).getGameBoard().isPaused()));
            }
        }

    }
}
```